# Regex to grab strings with a space at the end

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract some data from URLs in a LOG file and I'm almost there but the last part I am stuck on.

Here is the regex I have come up with so far,

```
(\?.*\s+)
```

Example of URLs I am working with

```
json?userId=1234&email=blahblah@blah.com HTTP/1.1
```

And I want to pull out

```
userId=1234&email=blahblah@blah.com
```

Across multiple lines of similar URL lines. The regex above gets the right stuff at the start but does not stop after the whitespace. What am I missing to make it not include the ? and end at the white space properly?

Edit: Clarified question a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in sed.

echo "json?userId=1234&email=blahblah@blah.com HTTP/1.1" | sed 's/.*?\(.*\)\s.*$/\1/

you might also try.
(\?[^\s]+)
match as many not space characters after a ?

Comment: I used (\?[^\s]+), but is there a way to NOT include the ?, testing it here, http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1):

I used to do it that way:

```
\?([^ ]*) -> \1
```

I do not know your implementation, but it's "working" on http://regexpal.com/ (this tester does not replace)

Edit: forgot the "?"